# How to implement sleep function in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, sleep

I'm developing a website in Angular 2 using TypeScript and I was wondering if there was a way to implement `thread.sleep(ms)` functionality.

My use case is to redirect the users after submitting a form after a few seconds which is very easy in JavaScript but I'm not sure how to do it in TypeScript.

Comment: Typescript is a superset of JavaScript. So write it in JavaScript, and there you go: you have a TypeScript solution.

Comment: This has got simpler since this question was originally answered. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39914235/328817

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65487714/1104877

Answer (score 524, accepted):

You have to wait for TypeScript 2.0 with `async`/`await` for ES5 support as it now supported only for TS to ES6 compilation.

You would be able to create delay function with `async`:

```
function delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) );
}
```

And call it

```
await delay(1000);
```

BTW, you can await on `Promise` directly:

```
await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 1000));
```

**Please note, that you can use `await` only inside `async` function.**

If you can't (*let's say you are building nodejs application*), just place your code in the anonymous `async` function. Here is an example:

```
    (async () => { 
        // Do something before delay
        console.log('before delay')

        await delay(1000);

        // Do something after
        console.log('after delay')
    })();
```

Example TS Application: https://github.com/v-andrew/ts-template

**In OLD JS you have to use**

```
setTimeout(YourFunctionName, Milliseconds);
```

or

```
setTimeout( () => { /*Your Code*/ }, Milliseconds );
```

However with every major browser supporting `async`/`await` it is less useful.

> Update:
> TypeScript 2.1 is here with `async/await`.

Just do not forget that you need `Promise` implementation when you compile to ES5, where Promise is not natively available.

> PS

You have to [export the function](https://github.com/v-andrew/ts-template/blob/master/src/lib/common.ts) if you want to use it outside of the original file.

Comment: **Update**: _async/await and generators support for ES5/ES3_ was moved to TypeScript 2.1

Comment: event without await, you can do delay(20000).then(()=>{

Comment: for some reason this didn't work for me `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)).then(()=>console.log("fired"));` but this worked `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>resolve(), 1000)).then(()=>console.log("fired"));`

Comment: @fjch1997, wrap it in `async` function. I added example

Comment: The declaration of 'delay' function does not need async keyword, as it already returns a promise.

Comment: @SlavaSt True. It wasn't there but someone convinced me to add it. Removing.

Comment: This worked great.  Just FYI, Resharper will flag Promise as being in an inaccessible module, but it works.  Just do a // ReSharper disable TsResolvedFromInaccessibleModule

Comment: in short for typescript: `const delay = (ms: number) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));` and use it like `await delay(5000)`

Comment: Thanks, This short code will do it easily
setTimeout( () => { /*Your Code*/ }, Milliseconds );

Comment: Correct way to do it nowadays is to use native node method ```import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises';```

Answer (score 169):

This works: (thanks to the comments)

```
setTimeout(() => 
{
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
},
5000);
```

Comment: I guess this one should be the accepted answer by now for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @StefanFalk Hi Stefan. I accepted the other answer because it included this answer and also had other, more "typescripty" ways of doing the delay which may be of interest to others. I'm personally using this one throughout my code since I don't see any benefit in using async/await for this specific task but I'm not a TS purist and I go with whatever's easier/more readable, so I agree with you in principle :).

Comment: I bumped it.  Clean and effective.

Comment: Although this deserves the upvote, this is not a real "sleep" functionality that we are used to. Our task gets executed after a certain time, but the thread itself never sleeps or waits. It just initiates another thread with a standing instruction to start after the given time.

Comment: Property 'router' does not exist on type 'ReportQueueDialog'.ts(2339)

Comment: One of the best answers, because it is very short and simple to implement.

Answer (score 36):

For some reason the above accepted answer does not work in New versions of Angular (V6).

for that use this..

```
async delay(ms: number) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>resolve(), ms)).then(()=>console.log("fired"));
}
```

above worked for me.

Usage:

```
this.delay(3000);
```

OR more accurate way

```
this.delay(3000).then(any=>{
     //your task after delay.
});
```

Comment: Just replace your '1000' with ms parameter call and it would be perfect.

Answer (score 29):

With `RxJS`:

```js
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

// ...

timer(your_delay_in_ms).subscribe(x => { your_action_code_here })
```

`x` is 0.

If you give a second argument `period` to `timer`, a new number will be emitted each `period` milliseconds (x = 0 then x = 1, x = 2, ...).

See the [official doc](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/timer) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for this perspective, came here to find the "observable way"

Comment: Cleanest solution IMO. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Or rather than to declare a function, simply:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('hello');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Why not a function?

Comment: not doing anything

Answer (score 11):

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

await timer(1000).pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
```

this works better for me

Comment: Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'.

Comment: import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: @AntonDuzenko you have to put it in .pipe()

Comment: Cannot find module 'rxjs' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Comment: A slightly newer take on this:
`await firstValueFrom(timer(1000));`
Both `firstValueFrom` and `timer` are from `rxjs`.
Or with an alias:
`const sleep = (ms: number) => firstValueFrom(timer(ms));`
Usage:
`await sleep(1000); nowDoSomething();`

Answer (score 8):

The correct way to do it from ES6 is

```
import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises';

await setTimeout(5000);
```

Its the native node method now. https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html

Comment: timers/promises is a Node.js-only API. It cannot be used in browser code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular5 and above, please include the below method in your ts file.

```
async delay(ms: number) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(()=>resolve(), ms)).then(()=>console.log("fired"));
}
```

then call this delay() method wherever you want.

e.g:

```
validateInputValues() {
    if (null == this.id|| this.id== "") {
        this.messageService.add(
            {severity: 'error', summary: 'ID is Required.'});
        this.delay(3000).then(any => {
            this.messageService.clear();
        });
    }
}
```

This will disappear message growl after 3 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use RxJS:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

async yourFunction() {
    yourCode;
    await this.delay(5000);
    yourCode;
}

delay(ms: number): Promise<any> {
    const dummyObservable = of();
    return dummyObservable.pipe(delay(ms)).toPromise();
}
```