# How does gauge_clear_state_level work with Javascript and Typescript?

Tags: getgauge

I am trying to understand how Gauge handles concurrent execution of tests and how it manages state. However, I don't get it how `gauge_clear_state_level` is supposed to work. I have created two small examples in Javascript and also Typescript and for both I don't see any effect.

In my `default.properties` it is set as follows:

```
...
gauge_clear_state_level = scenario
...
```

This is my test specification:

```
# Example specification A

## Example scenario A1

* foo "A1"
* bar "A1"
* foo "A1"

## Example scenario A2

* bar "A2"
* foo "A2"
* bar "A2"
```

The implementation in Typescript looks like this:

```
import { Step } from "gauge-ts";

export default class StepImplementation {

    private fooCounter: number = 0;
    private barCounter: number = 0;

    @Step("foo <x>")
    public async foo(x: string) {
        await delay(1000);
        this.fooCounter++;
        console.log("foo " + x + " (" + this.fooCounter + ")")
    }

    @Step("bar <x>")
    public async bar(x: string) {
        await delay(1000);
        this.barCounter++;
        console.log("bar " + x + " (" + this.barCounter + ")")
    }

}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/37764963
function delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) );
}
```

When I run the specification, the output is:

```
Running tool: gauge.cmd run c:\....\specs\exampleA.spec --simple-console --hide-suggestion
"Windows support is not tested yet. There might be some issues."
# Example specification A
  ## Example scenario A1
foo A1 (1)
bar A1 (1)
foo A1 (2)
  ## Example scenario A2
bar A2 (2)
foo A2 (3)
bar A2 (3)

Successfully generated html-report to => c:\....\reports\html-report\index.html
Specifications: 1 executed  1 passed    0 failed    0 skipped
Scenarios:  2 executed  2 passed    0 failed    0 skipped

Total time taken: 6.424s
Success: Tests passed.
```

What I would have expected is that both counters are reset after each scenario but the output above shows that this is not the case.

Any ideas or suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I did some more investigation and digged into the code of respective Gauge language runners. I did not find any usage of the `gauge_clear_state_level` property. I raised an issue in the Gauge project to update the documentation accordingly. They confirmed my findings and will remove the `gauge_clear_state_level` property from the documentation.

https://github.com/getgauge/docs.gauge.org/issues/291

The `gauge_clear_state_level` property is language specific, currently it is only supported by Java and .NET language runners. For all other languages one can use Data Stores to control the lifecycle of state information.