# Delay spinner interceptor Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, interceptor

I made spinner interceptor for http request. For every http request spinner is showing.

But  some web requests are relatively fast, in this case, the spinner will become a flicker in the web page.

I want to make some delay for spinner but i don't have idea how.

**Spinner component**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="loading$ | async">
<mat-progress-bar  mode="indeterminate" color='warn'>
</mat-progress-bar>
```

```
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit {
  loading$;

  constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading$ = this.spinnerService.isLoading$
    .pipe(
     delay(0)
    );
  }

}
```

**Spinner Service**

```
export class SpinnerService {
isLoading$ = new Subject<boolean>();

show() {
    this.isLoading$.next(true);
}
hide() {
    this.isLoading$.next(false);
}
```

}

**Spinner Interceptor**

```
export class SpinnerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
requestCount = 0;
constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.requestCount++;
        this.spinnerService.show();

    return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
            finalize(() => {
                this.requestCount--;
                if (this.requestCount === 0) {
                    this.spinnerService.hide();
                }
            })
        );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a timeout and have code executed after sometime in your `hide()` function
Here's an example

```js
     hide() {
       setTimeout( () => {     
        this.isLoading$.next(false);
       }, 2000 );
     }
```

There are a couple other methods to achive this, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37764963/5927361)

Answer (score 1):

You may use debounceTime rxjs operator inside pipe first afterthat use finalize method. 
Ex.

```
    import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.requestCount++;
        this.spinnerService.show();

     return next.handle(request)
            .pipe(
                debounceTime(1000),
                finalize(() => {
                    this.requestCount--;
                    if (this.requestCount === 0) {
                        this.spinnerService.hide();
                    }
                })
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

the answer: https://codeburst.io/rxjs-show-spinner-for-a-minimum-amount-of-time-807ac6b23227

Also, to achieve the opposite(not showing at all if a request is quick) take a look at [race](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/race) operator.