# vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.diff) - how do I get it to wait?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am issuing this command in my extension:

```js
export async function diffCompare(original: string, current: string) {
  await vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.diff", vscode.Uri.file(original), vscode.Uri.file(current));
  return;
}
```

however I am finding that it pops up the side by side display of the original file and the current file just fine but it is not waiting for the diff to be closed before proceeding.
I call the function with this:

```js
  await diffCompare(originalFile, developmentFile);
  const dj = "x";
```

I admit that I must be doing something wrong but cannot see what that might be. It is dropping immediately into the breakpoint I have set.

Any pointers as to what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: you have to monitor the close of the diff tab, a quick look at the API does not provide an `onDidxxxxx` that could be used to monitor tab close.

Comment: Does NOT provide...?

Comment: for Webview you have an `OnDidClose` event, I can't find one for close of Tab

Comment: would assume that there must be a means of not progressing till the DIFF is marked as complete.  In VSCode Command line DIFF there seems to be  a parm - WAIT but I can find no mention of it for use in an Extension.

Comment: if it is not in the API yet and you can make an argument why it could be useful you can make a feature request

Comment: I assume the diff editor, once opened, is treated like any other editor so there is no special `onDidCloseDiffEditor`.  For monitoring the close of an editor tab, see the documentation for `onDidCloseTextDocument` which directs you to use `onDidChangeVisibleTextEditors` which you will have to scan through to see if the diff editor is no longer visible.

Comment: Not exactly clear what you're doing since I've never used diff but can you use an regular delay? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764665/typescript-sleep

Comment: I need the user to complete his diff editing and to only then return control to the application.   There is a WAIT option on the diff command but it is not implemented for use within an  extension.

Comment: If you can't find a solution a workaround would be to create a status bar item when you create a diff. The text could read Click Here to Confirm Diff Edit or something like that. When you click it it can run any command you've created.

Comment: My diff is invoked via a right click option on a tree item. However it is followed by some other  function that requires the diff to have been completed. Unfortunately there is no ability to wait on the diff so it immediately drops into the follow on function giving the user no chance to complete the diff...

Comment: That's what I meant you could remove that function and have the user click the StatusBarItem to confirm the diff edit and then run the function. Alternative: You might be able to  use vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher() as well to watch the file but you may need to turn off auto save.