# setTimeout never ends in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, sleep

I try to implement a sleep method for a React Native application in Typescript. My implementation is the following:

```
sleep = (ms:number) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r, ms));
```

inspired by [How to implement sleep function in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764665/how-to-implement-sleep-function-in-typescript)

And I use it this way in a Component:

```
getData = async () => {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    await this.sleep(1000);
    const res = await getUser("test") ?? new User("", "", "", null, null, 0, 0);
    this.state.isLoading = false;
    this.setState({user : res, isLoading: false});
}
```

But using break points, I noticed that the code doesn't go further than `await this.sleep(1000);` and my application stays in loading state. What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: Typo: `() => r` the function you call when the timeout finishes **mentions** the resolve function but it doesn't **call** it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```js
sleep = (ms:number) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r, ms));
```

```js
sleep = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
// replace `() => r` with `r`
```

So the problem is, inside `setTimeout`, instead of execute function `r` you currently return a function `r` and `setTimeout` not using it.

```js
setTimeout(() => r, ms)
// same as
setTimeout(() => {
    // you doing nothing here
    return r; // setTimeout not using this
}, ms)
```

Learn more at document of `setTimeout` at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

##### Update:

- fix: `No overload matches this call`

```js
const sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve()
    }, ms);
});
```

Comment: With your suggestion I get the following error in VSCode: `No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(handler: () => void, timeout: number): number', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(value: unknown) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(handler: () => void, timeout: number): number', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(value: unknown) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.ts(2769)`

Comment: @Kantine I update the code, i make it a little bit longer version of it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the following:

```
sleep = (ms: number) => new Promise<void>(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
```